# How to unpack dictionary with lists into dataframe?

Tags: pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dictionary generated from a loop that looks like this:

```
dict_items([('cm_Classification0.1', [FP    16
TP    13
TN     1
Name: cm_Classification0.1, dtype: int64]), ('cm_Classification0.2', [TP    13
FP    12
TN     5
Name: cm_Classification0.2, dtype: int64]), ('cm_Classification0.3', [TP    12
FP    10
TN     7
FN     1
Name: cm_Classification0.3, dtype: int64]), ('cm_Classification0.4', [TP    11
TN     9
FP     8
FN     2
Name: cm_Classification0.4, dtype: int64]), ('cm_Classification0.5', [TN    11
TP     9
FP     6
FN     4
Name: cm_Classification0.5, dtype: int64]), ('cm_Classification0.6', [TN    13
TP     8
FN     5
FP     4
Name: cm_Classification0.6, dtype: int64]), ('cm_Classification0.7', [TN    15
FN     7
TP     6
FP     2
Name: cm_Classification0.7, dtype: int64]), ('cm_Classification0.8', [TN    16
FN     9
TP     4
FP     1
Name: cm_Classification0.8, dtype: int64]), ('cm_Classification0.9', [TN    17
FN    12
TP     1
Name: cm_Classification0.9, dtype: int64])])
```

I need a hand working out how to get this into a data frame where I've got the following columns: `cm_Classification#`,`FN`,`FP`,`TP`,`TN`. I've tried this `pd.DataFrame(list(values.items()))` but it returns me a data frame with the names in one column and then a list of the integers for each in the next column.

Here is the loop that generated the dictionary if that's any help:

```
classification_columns = question_two_partc.columns[3:12]
values = {column: list() for column in classification_columns}

for column in question_two_partc[classification_columns]:
    values[column].append(question_two_partc[column].value_counts())
```

Could anyone help me? Sorry for the mess! Let me know if any further information might be helpful!

Comment: Is possible create some test data for run your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need select first value of lists and `pd.concat`:

```
df = (pd.concat({k: v[0] for k, v in values.items()})
        .rename_axis(('A','B'))
        .reset_index(name='C'))
```